# IIS Basic Authentication with local user account allows blocked account

Tags: iis, basic-authentication, webdav

I've set up a WebDAV-enabled site on a regular Windows 10 Pro PC using IIS 10. The site is configured to require Basic Authentication (over HTTPS), with local user accounts.

This works, and the site only accepts valid logins, rejecting everything else.

However, even if I disable or block the local user account in Windows' local user management, the local account is *still* accepted as a valid login by IIS, and files can be downloaded.

I've configured the local user security policies to block accounts after 5 invalid login attempts. I can verify that the local account actually gets blocked after 5 deliberatly invalid attempts. But subsequent website-logins with correct credentials are accepted anyway. So it seems IIS completely ignores if the local user account is blocked/disabled, and just verifies that the credentials are valid.

Any suggestions to what kind of config I'm overlooking?

Comment: please check that what is the status of the anonymous authentication is that enable or disable? is that user is windows user? if yes then you could use iis windows authentication and set authorization rule in iis to allow and deny user for the whole site or for specific file or folder.

Comment: <system.webserver>
   <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true">
          <providers>
 <clear />
<add value="NTLM" />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
          </providers>
          <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />
        </windowsAuthentication>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="Administrators" />
          <deny users=”?”/>
      </authorization>

Comment: Anonymous authentication is disabled:

`<authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                    <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
</authentication>`

Comment: To clafify, access to the site is *only* possible with a valid username/password combination, specified as a local system user. There is just 1 user who needs access to the site, it's just for a private backup-destination over WebDAV. 

But the username/password combination remains valid, even when the user is disabled/blocked. I've been looking into credientials caching settings, but so far not found anything that works.

Comment: try to recycle the iis application pool and delete browser cache and history and try again to access the site.